# placing large image sprite in small div and adapt according to window resize

Tags: html, css, sprite, css-sprites

```
.icon-parkfinder_1 {
  background-image: url(../images/sprites.png);
  background-position: -1080px 0px;
  width: 1080px;
  height: 1920px;
}
```

I have a large image sprite and i placed it in small div. i expect it to be responsive. but it did not work. what should be styling for the 'div' to fit the image and adapt to window resizing

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you an image that will respond to fit to the size of the page.

```
.icon-parkfinder_1 {
  background-image: url(../images/sprites.png);
  max-width: 1080px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1920px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an background-size: cover to your div.

```
.icon-parkfinder_1 {
  background-image: url(../images/sprites.png);
  width: 1080px;
  height: 1920px;

  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```